# How to show items on RecyclerView Android based on the values of a child

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I need to retrieve some data on Firebase realtime database based on the values of a child.

[image: Firebase Instance]

For example, here I need to show only the child(notification) where `accepted==true`.

I pass my values on `RecyclerView` with a reference without creating a list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get all notifications "WHERE" `accepted` property holds the value of `true`, you need to use a query. In code, looks like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference notificationsRef = rootRef.child("Notifications");
Query query = notificationsRef.orderByChild("accepted").equalTo(true);
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(/* ... */);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this?

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/lists-of-data#filtering_data

You can use equalTo() method to filter data.

Comment: I tried .child("Notifications").orderBy("accepted").equalTo(true)